# Getting a TimeOut Error when trying to run a python code that transfers files from EC2 to Local

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2

This is the code on the AWS EC2 instance:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print (" New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        filename='mytext.txt'
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print ("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print ('Got connection from ', (ip,port))
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

And this is the code on my local machine:

```
import socket
import time

#TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_IP = 'ip-ec2-instance'
TCP_PORT = 60001

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

clock_start = time.clock()
time_start = time.time()

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        #print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        #print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            print ('file close()')
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')

clock_end = time.clock()
time_end = time.time()

duration_clock = clock_end - clock_start
print ('clock:  start = ',clock_start, ' end = ',clock_end)
print ('clock:  duration_clock = ', duration_clock)

duration_time = time_end - time_start
print ('time:  start = ',time_start, ' end = ',time_end)
print ('time:  duration_time = ', duration_time)
```

Now, the code on the EC2 instance seems to run fine and waits for a connection, but the code on my local machine gives me the error mentioned below when I try running it with the public IP of the EC2 instance:

**TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]** A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: The ports in the two codes are different and the server is only listening on `'localhost'`.  `time.clock()` was also deprecated in Python 3.3 and removed in Python 3.8.  When I made those fixes it worked, so please post the *actual* code that produces your issue.  The error message sounds like it could be blocked by a firewall.

Comment: The IP is same on both I just didn't want to post it because I don't wish to reveal my IP address. As for the firewall, I will check that out.